# ASP.NET Core SQL Linq using list of strings

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a list of strings like this

```
list = {a,b,c}
```

I would like to compare it in the database but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. This is my linq query:

```
var initialData = (from item in dbContext.DocumentCategories
    join df in dbContext.DocumentFields
    on item.Id equals df.DocumentCategoriesId
    join dfs in dbContext.DocumentFieldsStore
    on df.Id equals dfs.DocumentFieldsId
    select new SearchDocumentsListViewModel
    {
        CategoryId = item.Id,
        DocumentId = dfs.DocumentsId,
        FieldId = df.Id,
        Data = dfs.Data
    })
    .ToList();

initialData = initialData
    .Where(u => u.Data.Contains(list))
    .ToList();
```

Currently its showing me this error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'char'

Not sure what that means

Comment: Should the `Where` at the end be flipped to `.Where(u => list.Contains(u.Data))`? Seems like data might be a string.

Comment: Looks like it works. But why is that?

Comment: Because you were asking the question of "Does your string contain the list?" instead of "Does your list contain the string"

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now. Do you want to put it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Where` statement at the end that has the `Contains` expression backwards.

```
.Where(u => u.Data.Contains(list)
```

This line of code explained:
`u.Data` is being treated as a `char[]` and a `char` cannot contain a list.

This line of code needs to have the contains flipped around to:

```
.Where(u => list.Contains(u.Data)
```